# how to parse attribute onclick, which contains return function. javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a link which return form with different ID's, and i need to get ID number from onclick attribute

```
<a onclick="return package_order(14400287396);" href="javascript:;">advanced</a>
<a>doit</a>
```

this jquery code:

```
 var pack = $('a:contains("advanced")').attr("onclick");
 $('a:contains("doit")').click(function(){
    alert(pack)
```

and i get:

```
function onclick(event) {
  return package_order(14400287396);
}
```

but i need only id number inside()
should i use regular expression to do it? or what?

Comment: you could make the package order number the `id` of the anchor, easier to work with that way.

Comment: i know but, i cant do it right now, i need solution for this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracted 'id' from `onclick` attribute is this:

```
$('a:contains("advanced")').attr("onclick").match(/\d+(?=\))/)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
var idStr = pack.split('(')[1];
var id = idStr.substring(0, idStr.length-2);
```

which will split that string into an array based on the first left paren, and then take the second array value, then subtract the last 2 chars